# Why does the cursor not close in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have been trying every single thing but still some how have not been able to find a solution for this. In spite of using the close method the cursor still doesn't seem to be closing. This has been frustrating me. Any help will be much appreciated. Here is my code

```
public class Order extends Activity{    

DatabaseHelper helper;
Cursor c;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.order);
    String columns[] = {"_id", "Name", "Price"};
     helper = new DatabaseHelper(this); 
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
     c=db.query("lite", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
curs();
 c.close(); 
 helper.close();
}
public void curs()
{

String r = "";
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        r=r + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")) + "   "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))+"   "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price"));
         c.moveToNext();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to close the database to. Add `db.close()` after `helper.close()`

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
curs();
c.close(); 
helper.close();
```

to

```
curs();
if(!isClosed()){
     c.close(); 
     }
 helper.close();
 db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your database also, try this

```
db.close();
c.close();
helper.close();
```

Also, I suggest you can declare 'Cursor' as local variable instead of global and pass it as in argument to your method 'curs'